# Is there a way to find every combination to select an element from each list (in a list)?

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to find all combinations to select exactly one element from each list inside a list. (I prefer the computationally fastest method.)

**Example:**
If my list is [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6]] I would want to get the following result (in any order):
[[1,2,4], [1,2,5], [1,2,6], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,3,6]]

I tried finding functions in modules like itertools without any success and am not sure how to start this.

I was thinking about doing the following, but I have no idea how to finish this:
Find the number of permutations to find (called m here):

```
m = 1
for letter in letters:
    m *= len(letter)
```

Then set up a for loop:

```
for i in range(m):
```

Then find each combination by cycling through all lists in the list and taking one element. I was thinking of doing the selection somehow using the modulus (%) function, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: "I tried finding functions in modules like itertools" the answer is itertools product. Having said that, your approach to a solution is so weird, because you're trying to use indexes to iterate. Think of more pythonic loops, and this is much easier to tackle.

Comment: @AndrewAllen That helps to find a random element, but what do I do to find every element?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `itertools.product()`:

```py
>>> for x in itertools.product([1], [2,3], [4,5,6]):
...   print(x)
...
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
```

Comment: How do I enter a list of lists into this function?

Comment: For a list like [[1],[2,3,4],[5,6]] I get ([1],)
([2, 3, 4],)
([5, 6],)

Comment: problem resolved: you put a star in front